# Printing out elements of array after quicksort

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, quicksort

I found an implementation of the quicksort on a website. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int partition (int arr[], int l, int h)
{
    int x = arr[h];
    int i = (l - 1);

    for (int j = l; j <= h- 1; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] <= x)
        {
            i++;
            std::swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
        }
    }
    std::swap(arr[i + 1], arr[h]);
    return (i + 1);
  }

 /* A[] --> Array to be sorted, l  --> Starting index, h  --> Ending index */
 void quickSort(int A[], int l, int h)
 {
   if (l < h)
    {        
       int p = partition(A, l, h); /* Partitioning index */
       quickSort(A, l, p - 1);  
       quickSort(A, p + 1, h);
    }

  }

int main()
{
  int N;
  int l = 1, h = N-1;
  int i = 0;
  int array[N];
  std::cin >> N;
  for( int j = 0; j<N; j++)
  {
    std::cin >> array[j];
    j++;
  }
  quickSort(array, l, h);
  for( int k = 0; k<N; k++)
   {
     std::cout << array[k];
   }

  return 0;
  }
```

I added the bit at the end of the main() to print the array. Is this the correct way? As soon as I added that part, I started getting the segmentation fault error. How do I fix it?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) then **use a debugger** (`gdb`). But you really should use C++11 and its `std::sort`

Comment: That `main` is broken. My advice would be to stay away from wherever you found it.

Comment: That `main` won't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare your `array` and initialise `h` before you've initialised `N`, try:

```
std::cin >> N;
int* array = new int[N];
int h = N - 1;
```

Comment: You mean `std::vector<int> array( N );`.  There's never any reason in C++ to use an array new.

Comment: @JamesKanze absolutely, was just trying to keep it as close to the OP as possible.